# QGIS Label dragged manually doesn't repeat anymore

Tags: qgis, labeling

I would like to set some manual alignment for my labels. I tried to adjust them horizontally, but I had no option for doing so.
I decided then to move them manually, although I noticed, that they don't repeat anymore. I've set the Repeat 750, but it seems to not work when the manual option is used.

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't see another option for a horizontal shift when the Parallel option is used.

Is there a way of manual repeat the label?

Comment: I guess a bit more context is needed to understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Please describe the desired outcome more detailed. Currently I'd say "then don't manually drag the labels" would be a valid solution.

Comment: I've presented 2 options for how I coped with this issue. The first one is manual available in the main panel. Another one refers to the customization panel where I set the repeat value.